# Stopped with Exit Code = '-1073740791'. How can I debug it?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows service that is started and after some time it shuts down with the following exit code:

> -1073740791. STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN.

How can I debug? How do I know what is happening. Tried attaching with the debugger (with "Enable native code debugging" enabled) and selected all exceptions but it doesn't stop. The service just exits.

Comment: Have you checked the windows event log if there are any exceptions / stack traces for the service?

Comment: It would help if you caught and logged to a file all exceptions.

Comment: Do you use `unsafe` code or native interop (P/Invoke) in your service? If so, could you show us that code? The error means that there has been an overrun of a stack-based buffer in your service, something that should not be possible using (safe) managed code only.

Comment: Do you have the source code for this Windows service?